# Can i know email id's of user who have installed my app from playstore

Tags: android

I have uploaded app on playstore. Now i want to know email id of user who have downloaded my app. Can it be possible to know email ids of user?

Comment: Wouldn't that be against personal privacy? You need to ask user for that info when app is started.

Comment: Thanks @Rohit5k2. Actually i have lost keystore file. Now, I want  to know user email id's whom i can email and let them request to download new apk.

Comment: You can access email address only if user is using your app and you have specifically requested for that info. I assume you don't have that feature in your existing build so there isn't any way to get email id's.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 In app i have not requested any email id from user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to know who has downloaded your app. And it is also not possible to recover a keystore. Do your best to find that keystore.

Comment: I tried to recovery keystore by using some recovery software. But didn't able  to recover that file.

Comment: I am sorry. You have no choice but to upload a new app. Use the same name as a different version like "MyApp 2" so users will know this is an updated version.

Comment: Yes i am thinking to go with that final solution.

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct if you think it is the right one.

Comment: But i think so google should provide some mechanism get out of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can try to get in touch with the users of your app is by looking at the ratings in the dev console (you can see who reviewed your app) and by putting a new link into the description of the old app. Also there are some ways to avoid the keystore thing. I've read various solutions already here at SO.